# Why Synchronization not working properly with while extending to Thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, sleep, runnable

Currently, I'm studying "synchronization", while I was doing an exercise on the synchronization method I couldn't able to get a proper output but when I'm trying the same exercise by implementing Runnable it's working fine. I don't know why it's happening like this. could anyone please help me out here?

### By extending Thread

```
public class ClassRoom extends Thread {
    
    
    synchronized public void run() {
        
        
        try {
            
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " enters class room");
        
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " teaching students");
        
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " exits class room");
        
        
        } catch(InterruptedException ie) {
            ie.getMessage();
        }
    }

}
```

### By implementing Runnable

`public class ClassRoom  implements Runnable {`

rest of the codes are same

### Main method (by extending Thread)

```
public class ClassRoomApp  {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        

        ClassRoom physics_class = new ClassRoom();
        ClassRoom cs_class = new ClassRoom();
        ClassRoom english_class = new ClassRoom();
        
        physics_class.setName("Physics teacher");
        cs_class.setName("CS teacher");
        english_class.setName("English teacher");
        

        physics_class.start();
        cs_class.start();
        english_class.start();
        
    }

}
```

### Main method (by implementing Runnable)

```
public class ClassRoomApp  {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        
        ClassRoom class_room = new ClassRoom();
    
        Thread t1 = new Thread(class_room);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(class_room);
        Thread t3 = new Thread(class_room);
            
        t1.setName("Physics teacher");
        t2.setName("CS teacher");
        t3.setName("English teacher");
    
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();
        
    }

}
```

### These are the outputs im getting :

While implementing Runnable :

Physics teacher enters class room 
Physics teacher teaching students 
Physics teacher exits class room 
English teacher enters class room 
English teacher teaching students 
English teacher exits class room 
CS teacher enters class room 
CS teacher teaching students 
CS teacher exits class room

While extending Thread :

Physics teacher enters class room 
English teacher enters class room 
CS teacher enters class room 
English teacher teaching students 
Physics teacher teaching students 
CS teacher teaching students 
English teacher exits class room 
CS teacher exits class room 
Physics teacher exits class room

I've tried removing the Thread.sleep() from the Thread extended class then it sometimes working sometimes not woring.

These are the outputs :

### first try :

CS teacher enters class room 
Physics teacher enters class room 
Physics teacher teaching students 
English teacher enters class room 
Physics teacher exits class room 
CS teacher teaching students 
English teacher teaching students 
CS teacher exits class room 
English teacher exits class room

### second try : (works)

Physics teacher enters class room 
Physics teacher teaching students 
Physics teacher exits class room 
English teacher enters class room 
English teacher teaching students 
English teacher exits class room  
CS teacher enters class room 
CS teacher teaching students 
CS teacher exits class room

Comment: Please explain what your code is meant to do -- what do you expect to happen? What is happening that you don't expect? That is, what is "proper output"? Perhaps leaving the newlines in your output examples would make your question easier to understand.

Comment: But the answer is that in your first example you have three instances of ClassRoom and in the second you only have one, so `synchronized` does nothing in the first case.

Comment: "`ie.getMessage();`" does nothing. You should read up about how to handle exceptions, and specifically how to handle an `InterruptedException` (because it typically requires something different to other exception types).

Comment: in "implementing Runnable", 'classroom' is a shared resource with syncrhonized non-static method run(). Which means that only one thread can access the method at a time for a given Runnable object.  
On the contrary, In case of "extending Thread" you have 3 objects, and no concurrent access to this code happens.
When annotating non-static method as "syncrhonized", mutual exclusion happens per object. For static methods synchronized methods are locked per class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `Runnable` implementation, you are sharing a single instance across all threads. In the former, you are having 3 separate instances.

To match the behavior of separate threads with a runnable, you have to use separate runnables too:

```
public class ClassRoomApp  {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new ClassRoom()); // <- distinct instance
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new ClassRoom()); // <- distinct instance
        Thread t3 = new Thread(new ClassRoom()); // <- distinct instance
            
        t1.setName("Physics teacher");
        t2.setName("CS teacher");
        t3.setName("English teacher");
    
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();
        
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> while I was doing an exercise on the synchronization method I couldn't able to get a proper output but when I'm trying the same exercise by implementing Runnable it's working fine

So your "proper output" is when the output is synchronized that each teacher enters, teaches, and exits before other teacher output is displayed.

```
Physics teacher enters class room
Physics teacher teaching students
Physics teacher exits class room
English teacher enters class room
English teacher teaching students
English teacher exits class room
CS teacher enters class room
...
```

When you have the `synchronize` keyword on a non-static method, the lock that gets enabled when the method is called is applied on the *instance* of the object that contains the method.  In the case of the `ClassRoom` `Runnable`, each of the threads is sharing `class_room`:

```
ClassRoom class_room = new ClassRoom();
Thread t1 = new Thread(class_room);
Thread t2 = new Thread(class_room);
Thread t3 = new Thread(class_room);
```

In this case the same `ClassRoom` object instance is being locked by all 3 threads and the synchronization ensures that only one thread executes the `run()` method at a time.  Excellent.

Now let's look at the `Thread` case:

```
ClassRoom physics_class = new ClassRoom();
ClassRoom cs_class = new ClassRoom();
ClassRoom english_class = new ClassRoom();
```

In this case, there are 3 separate instances of `ClassRoom` so the `synchronized` keyword is locking on 3 different objects so each thread works independently.

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(new ClassRoom()); // <- distinct instance
```

Aside from the locking issue, you don't want to do this if `ClassRoom` extends `Thread` because you are creating 2 `Thread` objects – the `ClassRoom` and the `new Thread(...)` that wraps the `ClassRoom` but only starting one of them.  This is very confusing and unnecessary.  `ClassRoom` should implement `Runnable` instead.